# Would like to read in Two columns of dates but only get One

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text.csv file with 6 columns. I want 2 columns read in as dates for later differences.  However, I only get ONE column coming back as a **datetime**. Any ideas?

Also, I have several empty dates that return **nan NOT 0(zeros)** as in **na_values = 0**??

```
import pandas as pd
CSV = 'text.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(CSV, 
                 skiprows = 0, 
                 na_values = 0, 
                 parse_dates = ['Date of Sign Up', 'Birth Date'],
                 usecols = ['Date of Sign Up', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'Birth Date'])

df.info()  # Check info for column types and nan...
```

```
RangeIndex: 969 entries, 0 to 968
Data columns (total 6 columns):
Date of Sign Up  969 non-null datetime64[ns]
A                969 non-null object
B                969 non-null object
C                969 non-null object
D                969 non-null object
Birth Date       969 non-null object ## <== Why doesn't this column read as datetime?
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(5)
memory usage: 45.5+ KB
```

Comment: There is problem some values in `Birth Date` are contains at least one not parseable datetime, so `read_csv` silently not parse column.

Comment: Try `na_values='0'`?

Comment: Would you mind explaining more coherently what "Also, I have several empty dates that return nan NOT 0(zeros) as in na_values = 0" means?

Comment: @coldspeed I thought by adding 'na_values = 0' I could convert some of the nan's in my Birth Date column to zeros I could save a step, but that didn't seem to work out correctly either.

Comment: No, na_values=0 will convert 0s to NaNs, not the other way around. Also, NaN shouldn't be a problem, those will be converted to NaT.

Comment: @coldspeed good to know, ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem some values in `Birth Date` are contains at least one not parseable datetime, so `read_csv` silently not parse column.

You can check this values by:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df['Birth Date'], errors='coerce')

print (df.loc[dates.isnull(), 'Birth Date'])
```

---

Another solution is parse this problematic values to `NaT`:

```
df['Birth Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Birth Date'], errors='coerce')
```

I try test if `0` is correctly parsed to `NaT`:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""Date,a
2017-04-03,0
2017-04-04,1
0,2
2017-04-06,3
2017-04-07,4
2017-04-08,5"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), na_values = 0, parse_dates=['Date'])

print (df)
        Date    a
0 2017-04-03  NaN
1 2017-04-04  1.0
2        NaT  2.0
3 2017-04-06  3.0
4 2017-04-07  4.0
5 2017-04-08  5.0

print (df.dtypes)

Date    datetime64[ns]
a              float64
dtype: object
```

---

If there is a few non parseable values:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""Date,a
2017-04-03,0
string,1
0,2
2017-04-06,3
2017-04-07,4
2017-04-08,5"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), na_values = [0, 'string'], parse_dates=['Date'])

print (df)
        Date    a
0 2017-04-03  NaN
1        NaT  1.0
2        NaT  2.0
3 2017-04-06  3.0
4 2017-04-07  4.0
5 2017-04-08  5.0

print (df.dtypes)
Date    datetime64[ns]
a              float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: No, but I think it's time for you to take a break for the day :)

Comment: I like: df['Birth Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Birth Date'], errors='coerce')